# How to fix the trigger with check compiler log error?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Please, help!

I have trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_reservation BEFORE INSERT ON order
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE mistake INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) INTO mistake FROM order join reserving 
  on id_order = reserving.order_id_order
  WHERE reserving.room_num_room=:new.room_num_room
  AND  (order.reservation_from < :new.reservation_from AND :new.reservation_from < order.reservation_to) OR 
       (order.reservation_from < :new.reservation_from AND :new.reservation_to < order.reservation_to) OR
       (:new.reservation_from <= order.reservation_from AND order.reservation_to <= :new.reservation_to); 
  IF mistake>0 THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001,'reservation already exists');
  END IF;
END;
```

The idea of the trigger is not to allow make a reservation on already booked room. When I run it I had check compiler log error message. How can I change trigger?
I have following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE order (
    id_order                CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    reservation_from        DATE NOT NULL,
    reservation_to          DATE NOT NULL,
);

ALTER TABLE order ADD CONSTRAINT order_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_order );

CREATE TABLE room (
    num_room      CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    type          VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
);

ALTER TABLE room ADD CONSTRAINT room_pk PRIMARY KEY ( num_room );

CREATE TABLE reserving (
    room_num_room         CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    order_id_order        CHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE reserving ADD CONSTRAINT reserving_pk PRIMARY KEY ( room_num_room,
                                                                order_id_order );
ALTER TABLE reserving
    ADD CONSTRAINT reserving_order_fk FOREIGN KEY ( order_id_order )
        REFERENCES order ( id_order );

ALTER TABLE reserving
    ADD CONSTRAINT reserving_room_fk FOREIGN KEY ( room_num_room )
        REFERENCES room ( num_room );
```

Comment: You did not give the error you're getting, but from the code of your trigger, it's a mutating table issue: you're trying to select from the same table that the trigger is related to, and you cannot do this in a 'normal' 'for each row' trigger. Look at [this doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-E1150933-9B5F-4AA3-9F49-C222A1618BE5)

Comment: A couple of things seem off. 
1. You don't need the "DECLARE" keyword in your trigger definition.I suggest you check the documentation for valid syntax. 
2. "ORDER" is a reserved word in oracle (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_keywd001.htm#SQLRF55621). You should not use a reserved word as an identifier.

Comment: I translated names from czech language. So there were no problems except check compiler log error. I made this trigger from my teacher's example:

Answer (score 0):

I tried recreating the trigger with the statements above. The statements failed with several errors, it looks as if they were not tested before posting them as question. Please take some time posting a quality question.
Example:

```
CREATE TABLE room (
    num_room      CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    type          VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL, << this trailing comma makes this statement fail.
);
```

After fixing all errors I ran the "CREATE TRIGGER" and it errored out with

```
PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.ROOM_NUM_ROOM'
```

That is because the column ROOM_NUM_ROOM does not exist in the "ORDER" table.
If I remove the reference to 'NEW.ROOM_NUM_ROOM' the trigger compiles successfully.

However, as gsalem pointed out, this will not work because it will raise  a mutating table error. In the trigger code you cannot execute DML referencing the table that the trigger is on. There is plenty of documentation on how to avoid mutating table errors.